# Uncaught TypeError: sujet is not a function

Tags: javascript

Here I tried everything and nothing works and I do not understand why.

Then the goal and when users selects other I want to display an input topic but I have this error

[image: Screenshot of error message: "sujet is not a function"]

```
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <select id="selectsujet" onchange="sujet()">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choisissez une option</option>
      <option value="1">Demande Posteur</option>
      <option value="2">Demande 365 days</option>
      <option value="3">Report User</option>
      <option value="4">Demande de debannissement</option>
      <option value="5">Autre... (préciser)</option>
    </select>
    <label>Sujet</label>
</div>
<div id="sujet" style="display: none" class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
        <div align="center" class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="sujet" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="sujet">Sujet</label>
        </div>
    </div>               
</div>


<script>
    function sujet() {
        s = document.getElementById("selectsujet").value;
        if(s == "5")
        {
            $("#sujet").show();
        }else{
            $("#sujet").hide();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Haha, not enough information to solve the problem. Please show the real code you have. Notice also, that `id`s of the elements must be unique within the document.

Comment: Is this your actual html? or did you just paste the js under the html for this question?

Comment: I put your code into JSBin exactly as you added it here and it worked as expected - https://jsbin.com/rubojomune/edit?html,output

Could you show us how you're *actually* including the Javascript in your page because that's likely to be the problem

Comment: Ok its walking I change the name thanks to all for your help this and my first post and I'm not on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post this as a new answer because my first answer still relates to your "first" problem (you edited post).

**Working example**
(Might not be the exact correct code as you want it but it shows a working version and you should edit it to your needs)

**Extra (thanks to @Teemu)**
You have 2 id's with `sujet` in your question, those should be unique

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <select id="selectsujet" onchange="sujet()">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choisissez une option</option>
      <option value="1">Demande Posteur</option>
      <option value="2">Demande 365 days</option>
      <option value="3">Report User</option>
      <option value="4">Demande de debannissement</option>
      <option value="5">Autre... (préciser)</option>
    </select>
    <label>Sujet</label>
</div>
<div id="sujet" class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
        <div align="center" class="input-field col s12">
          <input type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="sujet">Sujet</label>
        </div>
    </div>               
</div>
<script>
 function sujet() {
        s = document.getElementById("selectsujet").value;
         if(s == "5")
    {
        $("#sujet").show();
    }else{
        $("#sujet").hide();
    }
    }</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your sujet() function in the script tag:

```
<script>
function sujet() {
    s = document.getElementById("selectsujet").value;
    if(s == "5")
    {
        $("#sujet").show();
    }else{
        $("#sujet").hide();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: because the function only reads from the div with id **#selectsujet**. It does not "ask" for a subject, so it expects you have already picked it

Comment: What I meant was that I forgot to put them in the question just above but in my code there are the tags

Comment: Are the tags in your code in the same place as they are in your question?